# How to achieve gradual color change in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with HTML tables and need to achieve gradual change color in a certain way. My desired result is to add a `red` class immediately, and then this color will change gradually to yellow.

I searched and I came up with the below code, but I couldn't figure out how to apply `transition: all 1s ease-in-out;`. Is there any method to achieve this?

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  $("td").addClass("red");
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* transition: all 1s ease-in-out; */
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that a comment in CSS is not ```//``` it's `/* commented code here... */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `transition` on the `yellow` class. Then you'll need a slight delay to allow the `.red` class to be added before you add the `.yellow` class. 50ms should be enough. Try this:

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  var $td = $(this).addClass("red");
  setTimeout(() => $td.addClass('yellow'), 50);
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red { background-color: red; }
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```